# Error when updating VertexBuffer with vulkan

Tags: c++, vulkan

I'm currently working on a Trail Renderer in a custom engine using Vulkan. I'm stuck when I try to **update the vertex buffer** of the mesh I use for the trail. I'm using a staging buffer.

Update Info error :
Those staging buffer seems to be the source of the error, the validation error is returning me "Cannot free VkBuffer 0x8838a700000004fe[] that is in use by a command buffer" when I try to render the mesh"

For the "update" pipeline I'm making sure that this is not while the graphic pass is made.

Here is the code for the update vertex buffer and index buffer

```c
template <typename T>
void Initialize(const std::vector<T>& vertices, const std::vector<uint32_t>& indices = {})
{
    static_assert(std::is_base_of<VertexMesh, T>::value, "T must derive from MeshVertex");

    if (!vertices.empty()) {
        std::vector<char> verticesData;
        verticesData.resize(sizeof(T) * vertices.size());
        std::memcpy(&verticesData[0], &vertices[0], sizeof(T) * vertices.size());

        const auto vertexStaging = Buffer(
                verticesData.size(),
                VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT,
                VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT,
                verticesData);

        //Optional 
        vertexBuffer_.emplace(
            sizeof(T) * vertices.
            size(),
            VK_BUFFER_USAGE_VERTEX_BUFFER_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT,
            VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);

        vertexCount_ = static_cast<uint32_t>(vertices.size());

        auto commandBuffer = CommandBuffer();

        VkBufferCopy copyRegion = {};
        copyRegion.size = sizeof(T) * vertices.size();

        vkCmdCopyBuffer(
            commandBuffer,
            vertexStaging.GetBuffer(),
            vertexBuffer_->GetBuffer(),
            1,
            &copyRegion);

        commandBuffer.SubmitIdle();
    }

    if (!indices.empty()) {
        const auto indexStaging = Buffer(
            sizeof(uint32_t) * indices.size(),
            VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_SRC_BIT,
            VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_VISIBLE_BIT | VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_HOST_COHERENT_BIT,
            indices);

        indexBuffer_.emplace(
            sizeof(uint32_t) * indices.
            size(),
            VK_BUFFER_USAGE_INDEX_BUFFER_BIT | VK_BUFFER_USAGE_TRANSFER_DST_BIT,
            VK_MEMORY_PROPERTY_DEVICE_LOCAL_BIT);

        indexCount_ = static_cast<uint32_t>(indices.size());

        auto commandBuffer = CommandBuffer();

        VkBufferCopy copyRegion = {};
        copyRegion.size = sizeof(uint32_t) * indices.size();
        vkCmdCopyBuffer(
           commandBuffer,
           indexStaging.GetBuffer(),
           indexBuffer_->GetBuffer(),
           1,
           &copyRegion);

       commandBuffer.SubmitIdle();
   }
}
```

This same function work when loading when loading an .obj or primitive

The constructor for my command buffer is:

```c
CommandBuffer(
    bool begin = true,
    VkQueueFlagBits queueType = VK_QUEUE_GRAPHICS_BIT,
    VkCommandBufferLevel bufferLevel = VK_COMMAND_BUFFER_LEVEL_PRIMARY);
```

And the SubmitIdle function:

```c
void CommandBuffer::SubmitIdle()
{
    const auto queueSelected = GetQueue();

    if (running_) { End(); }

    VkSubmitInfo submitInfo = {};
    submitInfo.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_SUBMIT_INFO;
    submitInfo.commandBufferCount = 1;
    submitInfo.pCommandBuffers = &commandBuffer_;

    //Code upadeted from Nicol Bolas tips
    CheckVk(vkQueueSubmit(queueSelected, 1, &submitInfo, nullptr));
    CheckVk(vkQueueWaitIdle(queueSelected));
}
```

I hope you have everything to see things more clearly than me!

Comment: What does your validation layers telling you? Also, what's the point in waiting for a fence if you're just going to wait for the queue to go idle?

Comment: For the  fence you're right. But removing it didn't fix the error. For my validation layer it was giving me more error (I already fix some of them (the descriptor was wrong) but still I cannot display my mesh and I have this error: 
"Cannot free VkBuffer 0x8838a700000004fe[] that is in use by a command buffer"

The adress is always different so I'm guessing that those are my stagings buffer